# error: 'const char* HTTPREQUESTS::certificate' is not a static member of 'class HTTPREQUESTS'

Tags: c++, arduino

Here's a general question I hope you can explain me. In case why you're wondering why I use `cstring` it's because the Arduino doesn't support for exampe `std` by default. However, my problem is the error

> error: 'const char* HTTPREQUESTS::certificate' is not a static member
>   of 'class HTTPREQUESTS'

```
#include <cstring>

char root_ca_sherz[128];
unsigned long now();


class HTTPREQUESTS {
  public:
    HTTPREQUESTS(char const strAddress[64] = "defaultAddress", char const strParameters [256] = "defaultParameters", bool bSendImmediately = false, char const *cert = root_ca_sherz);

    ~HTTPREQUESTS();

    bool sendRequest();

    char const *certificate;
    char parameters[256];
    char device[30];
    char address[64];
    unsigned long timestamp;
    int sendAttempts;
    bool sendImmediately;
    unsigned long lastSendAttempt;
};




HTTPREQUESTS::HTTPREQUESTS(char const strAddress[64], char const strParameters [256], bool bSendImmediately, char const *cert) {
  if(strcmp(address, "defaultAddress") == 0) {
    strcpy(address, strAddress);
    strcpy(parameters, strParameters);
    timestamp = now();
    certificate = cert;
  }
}

char const *HTTPREQUESTS::certificate="";

char HTTPREQUESTS::parameters[256]="defaultParameters";
char HTTPREQUESTS::device[30];
char HTTPREQUESTS::address[64] = "defaultAddress";
unsigned long HTTPREQUESTS::timestamp=0;
int HTTPREQUESTS::sendAttempts=0;
bool HTTPREQUESTS::sendImmediately = false;
unsigned long HTTPREQUESTS::lastSendAttempt=0;


int main()
{

}
```

Actually the content is seperated in two files (.h, .cpp) but for testing purposes I combined them in the main.cpp file.

I don't understand why I should declare the member variables as `static` because I basicly just don't want it. First because the variables should not be available without initialization and second they will be different for every object after initialization. In my understanding these two functionalities result from setting a member as `static` - please correct me if I'm wrong, I'm very new to C++.

The objects from this class are instantiated temporary (by `new`) and deleted after usage.

So what do I need to do to use the code as intended without the `static` keyword?

Comment: You are trying to initialize them as static class members.

Comment: Actually I intended to define them, not to initialize them... What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These class members are already declared in the class.

You probably want this:

```
class HTTPREQUESTS {
public:
  HTTPREQUESTS(char const strAddress[64] = "defaultAddress", char const strParameters[256] = "defaultParameters", bool bSendImmediately = false, char const* cert = root_ca_sherz);

  ~HTTPREQUESTS();

  bool sendRequest();

  char const* certificate = "";

  char parameters[256] = "defaultParameters";
  char device[30];
  char address[64] = "defaultAddress";
  unsigned long timestamp = 0;
  int sendAttempts = 0;
  bool sendImmediately = false;
  unsigned long lastSendAttempt = 0;
};
```

And drop this alltogether:

```
char const *HTTPREQUESTS::certificate="";

char HTTPREQUESTS::parameters[256]="defaultParameters";
char HTTPREQUESTS::device[30];
char HTTPREQUESTS::address[64] = "defaultAddress";
unsigned long HTTPREQUESTS::timestamp=0;
int HTTPREQUESTS::sendAttempts=0;
bool HTTPREQUESTS::sendImmediately = false;
unsigned long HTTPREQUESTS::lastSendAttempt=0;
```

Latter would only be necessary if all those class members were `static`, which is not the case here and which is not your intention as far as I understood.